# Thinkpad docking station audio fails randomly

Tags: sound, thinkpad, docking

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (7th Gen, I think?), with a USB-C Lenovo-branded docking station for it.  The laptop spends most of its time plugged into the docking station, and generally works fine; video output to the attached monitor is steady.

Audio is another matter.  I have speakers plugged into the docking station (aux jack), as well as a USB dongle for a wireless headset.  On boot, everything works fine and audio plays out of the speakers just fine.  However, seemingly randomly (could be an hour later, could be a week later) the computer loses the audio output through the docking station.  It still sees the USB dongle for my headphones, but not the docking station's audio out.  I have yet to observe a pattern to when the audio dies, but after it does the all of my settings simply do not recognize that the dock audio out even exists as a piece of hardware.  It simply doesn't show up in any config panels.

A reboot always fixes it, quite reliably.  None of the cables involved are touched at all at any point, so it seems like it's not just a loose cable somewhere.

This has happened continually on at least Kubuntu 19.10, 20.04, and 20.10 now.  Any idea what the issue could be?  (It's working at this moment so it's difficult to troubleshoot; I don't know when it will next die.)

Comment: Is it happening after system goes to sleep mode?

Comment: Nope.  The system is rarely in sleep mode, and I've had it happen to me right in the middle of a Meet call before, or while listening to music, or while it's idle.